# bash string incorrectly split

Tags: bash, git

I have this script

```
#!/bin/bash
function clone {
    url=$(cli-tool "$1" that finds url)
    echo $url
    $(git clone ${url})
}
```

echo prints the correct url in the format
"https://gitprovider.com/Example/_git/Repo%20Name" (not a real url but that mimics the real url)

But git clone outputs

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'Repo%20Name"': Invalid argument
```

If I execute

```
git clone "https://gitprovider.com/Example/_git/Repo%20Name"
```

the correct repo will be cloned.

So why isn't

```
$(git clone ${url})
```

Working?

Comment: missing quotes!

Comment: @karakfa $(git clone "${url}")
has the same result

Comment: You don't need the `$(...)`, because you don't want to execute the *output* of `git clone` as a command.

Comment: @chepner `git clone ${url}`  both with and without `${url}` quoted has the same result as `$(git clone ${url})`

Comment: Quoting `${url}` is a good idea to accommodate all legal URLs. Dropping the command substitution is *necessary* because it serves no purpose other than to generate an error.

Comment: For a good many URLs, getting the same result with or without quotes is to be expected.

Comment: @chepner both `git clone "$url"` and `git clone $url` are giving me the same error as `$(git clone ${url})`

Comment: Then something is wrong with the value of `$url` itself that we can't diagnose, if typing the URL out manually works. What is the output of `echo "$url" | od` (*with* the quotes)?

Comment: the output of `echo git clone "${url}"` is the correct clone command which works if I copy and paste it into a new terminal window

Comment: It sounds like the `url` variable has nonprinting characters that're messing things up (but look ok when printed). Try the `od` command @chepner suggested to see what's lurking in the string.

Comment: For example, given `foo=$'1\r2'` and `bar=2`, the output of `echo "$foo"` and `echo "bar"` may *look* the same, but the bytes written by `echo` in each case are quite different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command substitution is only needed when you want to use the output of a command as an argument to another command. In your case, the output of `git clone` is then parsed as sequence of words used to build a command line. You don't want to do that; you just want `git clone ...` to run and have its output displayed on the terminal.

Compare

```
 $ echo $(echo foo)
 foo
 $ $(echo foo)
 bash: foo: command not found
```

You just want `git clone "$url"`, not `$(git clone "$url")`.

Comment: `git clone "$url"` has the same result

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$(git clone ${url})`, just use `git clone "${url}"`, i.e., drop the `$(`  `)` thing.

Comment: `git clone "${url}"` has the same result

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the url.. `%20` may be a problem.

Comment: I thought that too but the error is `fatal: could not create work tree dir 'Repo%20Name"'` which to me implies that the string was mangled before the `%20`

Comment: what is the output of `echo git clone "${url}"`?

Comment: The output is `git clone "https://gitprovider.com/Example/_git/Repo%20Name"` which if pasted in a terminal clones the correct repo. So wtf is happening here?

Comment: Perhaps you should urlencode your $url. Take a look at this link please: `https://gist.github.com/cdown/1163649`